# IIS Forms Authentication throws a 401 Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication, http-status-code-401

We are currently setting up forms authentication for our web app.
The plan is for users to be redirected to a login page on our main system when they want to access files.

IIS Settings

[image]

Setting the IIS "Authentication" to anonymous gives access to the files.

BUT when we change the authentication to "Forms" and disable everything else we are met with a constant 401 error when trying to access the file.

401 Error

[image]

There is no redirect. It just throws this error.
The Web config has been changes to allow "?" (anonymous) and allow="*".
This does not change the 401 error.

When anonymous access is enabled (alongside forms auth) there is **no redirect**. The users have direct access to the files.  (As if forms authentication is not even enabled?

Web Config

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278649/iis7-forms-authentication

Followed this guide. When enabling anonymous authentication and setting the web config to deny "?" users , it gives full access without redirecting. So it is still not working.

Comment: The problem is that, by default, Forms Authentication is only enabled for .ASPX files and in my application I have .HTML files since the client is in Adobe Flex. To fix it you have to go (in IIS Manager 7) to Modules, then Edit DefaultAuthentication module and deselect the checkbox that limits the authentication to .aspx files. Then you have to do the same for the FormsAuthentication module.

Hello everyone! After 4 hours of struggle i found this! Make sure you disable the forms authentication one too, Now mine works! We are even redirecting to another site to do the authentication.

Comment: To enable forms authentication on everything, you need to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline#enabling-forms-authentication-for-the-entire-application

Comment: Please note that I also had to add machine keys to my web.config and also had to add the domain name in the authentication tags. The machine key also had to be the same between domains and specified in the web.config. After also adding a cookie.domain in my C# side the authorisation is finally working between domains. I hope this helps someone.  :)

Comment: If you do want to help someone else, you should post your own answer below and accept it. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I also had to add machine keys to my web.config and also had to add the domain name in the authentication tags (also in the web config). After also adding a cookie.domain in my C# side the authorisation is finally working between domains.
--This has to be done when working with 2 subdomains. Eg: 1.website.com and 2.website.com.